# On surfaces of general type wich saturate the BMY-inequality

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-surfaces

Let $\mathbb{K}$ an algebraically closed field of characteristic $0$, let $X$ be a smooth minimal surface of general type.

It is known that surfaces satisfy, among other thing, the (Bogomolov-Miayoka-Yau) inequality $3c_2(X)\geq c_1(X)^2$ [2, Proposition 7.1]. If $X$ saturates this inequality then $\Omega_X^1$ and $K_X$ are ample, and for any curve $C$ on $X$ one has the inequality $\displaystyle2g(C)-2\geq\frac{1}{3}K_X\cdot C$ [1, Corollary 4.3]. Moreover, if $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{C}$ then these surfaces are all and only quotients of $\mathbb{B}_2\subset\mathbb{C}^2$ (the open complex ball) [3, Theorem 4].

1. If $\mathbb{K}\neq\mathbb{C}$, under the hypothesis $3c_2(X)=c_1(X)^2$, are known example of such surfaces?
2. If $\Omega_X^1$ and $K_X$ are ample, and for any curve $C$ on $X$ the inequality $\displaystyle2g(C)-2\geq\frac{1}{3}K_X\cdot C$ holds, is $3c_2(X)=c_1(X)^2$?

---

**Bibliography**

[1] U. Bruzzo, A. Capasso, B. Graña Otero - *Positivity for Higgs vector bundles*. **arXiv:2307.16578 [math.AG]**

[2] Y. Miyaoka - *The Chern classes and Kodaira dimension of a minimal variety*, Algebraic geometry, Sendai (1985) 449--476. Adv. Stud. Pure Math. **10**, North-Holland Publishing Co. (1987) Amsterdam.

[3] S.-T. Yau - *Calabi's conjecture and some new results in algebraic geometry*. Proc. Nat. Acad. Sci. **74** (1977) 1798--1799.

Comment: I do not understand your first question.  Every such surface over an algebraically closed field $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is the base change of a surface defined over an algebraically closed subextension $\mathbb{Q}\subset L\subset K$ that also admits a field extension $\mathbb{Q}\subset L \subset \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: The inequality $2g(C)-2\geq \frac{1}{3} K\cdot C$ is very weak: it holds as soon as $C^2\geq 0$ and $C\cdot K\geq 0$. Just take a general complete intersection surface of sufficiently high degree.

Comment: @JasonStarr If I extend the field, I can use the base change and I understand your comment. But if I restrict the field: how can I do this?

Comment: This is the "Lefschetz principle": define $L$ to be the algebraic closure of the smallest subextension of $K/\mathbb{Q}$ that contains all coefficients of the defining equations of your surface.  This is the algebraic closure of a finitely generated extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, hence $L$ is isomorphic to a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$.